# Get the parameters (variables) from my DataLayer GA4 API

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, looker-studio, google-datalayer

Currently I am using the GA4 API to trigger a custom event from my nodejs code.
Everything is working, however, I can't seem to keep the datalayer parameters to use in a GA4 report or Google Data Studio.

```
  events: [
  {
    name: "countRenterAccount",
    params: {
      numberRenter: countRenterAccount,
      eventTime: now,
    },
  } ...
```

The event appears in GA4 with the right parameters with the right values assigned, but it only keeps the number of times the event occurred without keeping my **numberRenter : countRenterAccount** or **eventTime: now** parameters.

I tried everything though:

- I created a custom dimension on GA4, but on Google Data Studio there seems to be nothing as value.
- I created a custom event that is triggered if **countRenterAccount** occurs taking into account my parameters. But it doesn't work, I have the impression that it doesn't work.

I am stuck on it for several days and I can't find a solution.
Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this the structure you are using to send the events to GA4: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#send_an_event? When you go into debug mode, do you see the events coming through and the parameters come across with the events?

Comment: Hello, yes this is the same structure, and the event is coming on GA4. When I unleash the event and I go to GA4 in the "real time" mode, I see my event that arrives with and the parameters (which have the right values). Except that these parameters are only visible in the real time mode, I can't get these values to use them. I tried too custom dimension like this : [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/zlUqxO_PQCuC)

Comment: When you look at reports inside Explore of GA4 do the dimensions show up there? When you setup the data studio data source, was this before or after you setup the custom dimensions? You might need to refresh your source in there and it will give you an onscreen prompt that fields were added. From my experience it won't automatically do it unless you go into the source and view the fields.

Comment: Hello, my custom dimension was empty but this morning I notice that it finally has a value, probably the right one. However, it is not usable in number. For example, I want to make a graph that displays for every day (by date) the value **numberRenter**.  [Look at this](https://prnt.sc/r3oJ5Lrhp_-W), my value "54" seems to be like a title, not usable in terms of number. Any idea ? :(

Comment: For the metric or value, try using events as the metric with the custom dimension. What does it look like? Also, it takes 48 hours for custom dimensions to show up in GA4. There is some documentation somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: It's working with this tutorial https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-work-with-text-data-type-in-google-data-studio/ to cast Text to Number. Thank you for your help ! :)